# Localhost displays only NGINX welcome page after running my app Angular application container

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I want to dockerize my Angular 17 application.
This is my dockerfile

```
# Stage 1: Build the Angular application
FROM node:18.14 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build -- --configuration production

# Stage 2: Serve the Angular application using Nginx
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/dwir-app /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I built my dockerfile and runned a container from the image of my application on port 4201:

```
docker run -d --name dwira_website_version2 -p 4201:80 dwiraversion1
```

I verified using docker ps that my container is running and tried to access my application using http://localhost:80 and I only get the welcome page of nginx. I tried also http://localhost:80/index.html and had the same result

I tired to see my app on localhost and didn't work because I only see the welcome page of NGINX.

this is my nginx.conf file:

```
    server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html ;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does your build process in fact produce an `index.html` file (independently of Docker)?  If you `docker run --rm dwiraversion1 ls /usr/share/nginx/html`, is your built application actually there?

Comment: the ls command provided me the content of my dist file which is dwir-app and inside it there is the browser and server files

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that I didn't have the index.html file while copying to /usr/share/nginx/html. I had to change my dockerfile like this:

```
# Stage 1: Build the Angular application
FROM node:18.14 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build -- --configuration production

# Stage 2: Serve the Angular application using Nginx
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*  <--- added this to clean the cache
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/dwir-app/browser /usr/share/nginx/html/ <---- here i added /browser because the index.html file is in the /browser 
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```